# ERROR in JSON Header while writing in JAVA

Tags: java, json

I'm getting error while posting JSON data in java, error states that, unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
I feel it's because of Authorization.
Can anyone please guide me how to write Authorization header in JSON for JAVA..

Comment: kindly try posting some example code clearly mentioning your problem and stacktraces if any

Comment: please at least copy paste exact error.

Comment: can you share some code, like the JSON object and the Java code

Comment: Hi. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to properly ask a question.

For now the relevant parts of your code and the occurred error message would help to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Share your code and detail explanation.
Below is the code to add header in request using okhttp.

```
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient(); 

 Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("add api url")
        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        .addHeader("Authorization", "add auth header here")
        .build();
```

For reference [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes)